# How Do I correctly use vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying the following:

I have a login form that uses axios to get results from a rest api. When submitting the correct data I get returned all user data, when submitting the wrong data I get a error message.

I'd like to save the userdata to a global store to use within my vue application. And I figured that vuex would work for this szenario.

Within my main.js I defined vuex and a mutation function to get the user data.

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
// other imports

const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      userData: {}
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    addUserData (state, data) {
      state.userData = data
    }
  }
})


createApp(App)
  .use(router, store)
  .mount('#app')
```

within my Login.vue I'm trying to use the store I created earlier:

However, when trying to use the mutation for the store `addUserData` I get `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: store is not defined` in the console. How do I now correctly use the function?

I tried using `this.$store.state.addUserData` as well and end up with a different error

```
<template>
  <div class="container content">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="login">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="username" class="form-label">Username:</label>
        <input type="username" id="username" v-model="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
      
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="password" class="form-label">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" v-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;&bull;">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {

  data(){
    return {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {

    async login() {

      axios.get('https://localhost:9443/isValidUser', 
      {
        params: {
          user: this.username,
          pass: this.password,
        }
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)

        if(response.data[0].username) {

          console.log("Hello " + response.data[0].username)
          store.commit('addUserData', response.data[0])

        } else {
          console.log("Login failed")
        }
      })

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's this.$store, not store, so `this.$store.commit('addUserData', response.data[0])` should work

Comment: Hi @Lk77, thanks for your reply. apparently I messed up importing vuex or the store. maybe both. When using your suggestion I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commit')`

Comment: Try to use : `.use(router).use(store)` i think you can have multiple plugins per use() call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution to use multiple plugins at "once" is that :

```
const app = createApp(App)
[store, router].forEach((p) => app.use(p));
app.mount('#app);
```

if you have a lot of plugins it can be handy, if not you can always do :

```
createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(store)
  .mount('#app')
```

for two plugins it's ok

So in the end your store is not used and hence the error

Comment: Thanks Lk77, that solved the issue. I wasn't aware to use them seperately.